# How can I implement this UI in Android

Tags: java, android, uiview

[image]

I want to create an UI as shown in the figure, not exactly, though, but similar. How can I implement this?

Comment: what have u tried yet and be specific what problem you are facing?

Comment: This is a hugely vague question that's likely to be closed as it's not asking anything specific. My recommendation would be to [search for some Android user interface tutorials](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&xhr=t&q=android+gui+tutorials&cp=21&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=android+gui+tutorials&pbx=1&fp=d1d9a4fad2915874). Then when you have some specific questions about things you don't understand, come back to SO and ask them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to make one xml file and put it into drawable folder .

### rounded_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ababab"
            />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"
             /> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Now make another xml file in which set textview and edittext .

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

<TextView android:text="Initial"  android:textColor="#686868"
        android:id="@+id/lable" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></TextView>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/r_email" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp" android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:hint="Initial" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#ababab" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

<TextView android:text="Initial"  android:textColor="#686868"
        android:id="@+id/lable" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></TextView>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/r_email" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp" android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:hint="Initial" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Table Layout to design such a View or also you can use a Tool for UI design Called Droid Draw.. Download the .exe file and install in your PC and start Design [Droid Draw UI design Tool](http://www.droiddraw.org/)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/white"/>
<corners android:radius="10px" />
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use tablelayout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableRow>
<TextView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:text="First Name"
 />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<TextView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:text="Last Name"
 />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the recipe.

1. Take 3 images as below
   1.1 Top rounded corner
   1.2 middle image (sharped corner)
   1.3 Bottom rounded corner
2. Take the Text view and set the above images as background.

Use `LinearLayout` with orientation `vertical`