# android view, error in parsing xml file

Tags: java, android, view

hi in my app i am trying to make an text view and edit box in a same line as if in iPhone apps.

after getting some info in the following link
[How can I implement this UI in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297154/how-can-i-implement-this-ui-in-android),

i created the two xml file. the following is my main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/back"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:paddingLeft="10dp">


      <TextView android:text="Initial"
                android:textColor="#686868"
                android:id="@+id/wideget02"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </TextView>

      <EditText android:id="@+id/widget01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:hint="Initial"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip"
         android:background="#ababab"/>

   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:paddingLeft="10dp">
      <TextView android:text="Initial" android:textColor="#686868"
                android:id="@+id/widget02" android:textSize="10sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

      <EditText android:id="@+id/widget01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp" android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:textSize="15sp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:hint="Initial"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Following is the back.xml file which i have placed in `drawable` of resource folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ababab"/>

   <padding android:left="1dp"
            android:top="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:bottom="1dp"
         />

   <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When i run the app it shows the following errors in logcat

```
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1631)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at com.gis.ss.main.onCreate(main.java:16)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1132)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
03-24 11:51:40.191: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(638):     ... 11 more`
```

what it refers too, please explain me..

Comment: hey where is your back.xml ? i cant see it .

Comment: sorry here it is     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">   <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ababab"
        />  <padding android:left="1dp"
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"
         /><corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> </LinearLayout>

Comment: hi Chirag using ur example i am able to create the same view, but i cant type anything there. how to type in the edit box......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root element of your `back` drawable must not be a `LinearLayout`. Looks like you need a `shape` there.

See this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

Comment: hi using ur link i am able clear my error, but i cant type anything there. how to type in the edit box......

Comment: As you can see in the first xml part ie main.xml file, i have placed an edit text box, i am not able to type anything there