# Can't type in the edittext of Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried using the answer posted by Chirag and Venkatesh in the following link: [How can I implement this UI in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297154/how-can-i-implement-this-ui-in-android)

I can create the UI but I can't type anything there. How do I type in those edit text boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you see is the TextViews laid out on top of the EditBoxes. Try to remove the TextViews from main.xml and see if you are able to edit.

Answer (score 0):

if you are setting a on key listener to the same  edit text , make sure that the return is "false" , if it is true the typing in the soft keypad will not be reflected in the edit box.

Source : while working with the recycleview , i had an edit text in the recycle view layout , on typing in edit text the typing did not reflect in the edit text so i did the above mentioned changes to make it alright.

Comment: Please mark your code as code using edit. So e.g. on key becomes `on key`