# Is it possible to make a TableLayout like this in Android?

Tags: android, tablelayout

Is it possible to make this in Android..If it is, can you give me an example?

[image: tableview]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply achieve this by using linear layout also . Please read this answer .

[How can I implement this UI in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5297154/614807)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.You can create row with different height.And you have to style your table layout so that it looks like as you want

Answer (score 0):

Instad of table layout ,this can be achieved by  [List view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) as it appears to be more like a list